# Quickbooks Payment API - ACH Payment using Java SDK

Tags: quickbooks

One of the assignment I am working on needs to receive payment using ACH on Quickbooks Payment. I have tried below code snippet to receive the payment via ACH (I would say Bank account).

```
    TokenService tokenService = new TokenService(requestContext);
     
    BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount.Builder().name("Test").accountNumber("11000000333456781").phone("1324567890").accountType(AccountType.PERSONAL_CHECKING)      .routingNumber("322079353").country("US").inputType(BankAccountInputTypeEnum.KEYED).build();
      
    Token tokenRequest = new Token.Builder().bankAccount(bankAccount).build();
     
    Token token;
    Charge charge = null;
     
    try {
        token = tokenService.createToken(tokenRequest);

    System.out.println("getIntuit_tid:::" + token.getIntuit_tid());
    System.out.println("value:::" + token.getValue());
     
    PaymentContext context = new PaymentContext.Builder().mobile("false").isEcommerce("true").build();
     
    Charge chargeRequest = new Charge.Builder().amount(new BigDecimal("5.55")).token(token.getValue()).currency("USD").context(context).build();
     
    //set a new request id
    // requestContext.setRequestId(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", ""));
     
    ChargeService chargeService = new ChargeService(requestContext);
     
    // Capturing the charge
    // chargeRequest.setCapture(true);
        System.out.println("QuickbooksPaymentApiService.createChargeFromToken(): Charge: " + com.intuit.payment.util.JsonUtil.serialize(chargeRequest));
     
    charge = chargeService.create(chargeRequest);
     
    System.out.println("getIntuit_tid:::" + charge.getIntuit_tid());
    System.out.println("charge id:::" + charge.getId());
     
  } catch (BaseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Exception while calling API " + e.getMessage());
    throw e;
}
```

With the above code snippet when I run the scenario, it throws some strange error:

```
    ERROR 2828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.intuit.payment                       : Bad Request Exception 400
    com.intuit.payment.exception.BadRequestException: ERROR CODE:PMT-4002, ERROR MESSAGE:number is required., ERROR DETAIL:number, ERROR INFO LINK:https://developer.intuit.com/v2/docs?redirectID=PayErrors, ERROR MORE INFO:null, ERROR TYPE:invalid_request
     
            at com.intuit.payment.services.base.ServiceBase.sendRequest(ServiceBase.java:141)
            at com.intuit.payment.services.ChargeService.create(ChargeService.java:87)
```

I am trying this with a Quickbooks Sandbox account with mock data. From the API document, all the required fields are set. Can anyone please guide what could be missing here?

Is this the right way to execute ACH payment via Quickbooks Payment API with Quickbooks Java SDK?

I tried code snippet posted in description section